# How to increase limit of array?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

```
// C Program to find average of numbers given by user
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
    double sum = 0;
    int ii = 0,c;
    char buf[256], *token;
    printf("Enter the numbers to average on a single line, separated by space and press enter when done\n");
    fgets(buf, 255, stdin);
    token = strtok(buf, " ");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        sum += atof(token);
        ii++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");  //Get next number
    }
    printf("Average is %lf", sum / (double)ii);
}
```

On line 8:

```
char buf[256], *token;
```

when I change the array limit to any 8 or more digit numbers like 11111111, 68297907 (and so on...) then the program gets complied but on output it shows `Segmention Error`.

How can I increase array limit? I am using a UNIX based system.

Comment: You could try malloc, but I don't see why 1111 wouldn't work.

Comment: char buf[4000]; works for me on Linux.

Comment: You have to increase the stack size available to your application. But 1111 and 6829 and 5736 should all work.

Comment: On my PC, char buf[100000] works fine.

Comment: It may be prudent to post the code that _doesn't work_ as expected

Comment: That should work, your bug is probably where you are using the array, possibly going beyond its bounds.

Comment: edit: I cant use more than 7 digits. any solution?

Comment: Check the buffer size available to the program you're using.

Comment: In addition to the seg fault issue (probably stack size, although seems smallish), also note you get to divide by zero if the user inputs nothing.

Comment: Welcome to [stack overflow](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt). Literally.

Comment: @Claudio: 100000 bytes are only (less than) ~100KB, while the OP's array size is **tens** of MB

Comment: @NeilKirk: 1111 and 11111111 are a **big** difference

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The question was edited. It used to be 1111.

Answer (score 4):

```
char buf[11111111];
```

This is over 11 megabytes. It's allocated on the stack. The stack has a finite size, often 8 or 10 megabytes. You're getting a stack overflow, which normally results in a [segfault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) if you exceed that limit.

You can:

- Increase the stack limit, if your system supports it. You don't tell us what kind of system you're on. This is normally done through the shell. For bash, run e.g.

  ```
  ulimit -s 12000
  ```

  to set the max stack size to 12000 kilobytes (120 megabytes). There might be a limit set by an administrator that prevents you from using this much stack space. You must run your program in the same shell as you ran the above `ulimit` command.
- Dynamically allocate the memory:

  ```
  char *buf = malloc(11111111);
  ```
- Allocate the space somewhere else besides the stack:

  ```
  static char buf[11111111];
  ```

I would question the need for allowing someone to input 11 megabytes of data on one line though.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to increase the stack size allowed:

http://www.ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html

or you could try allocating memory dynamically rather than on the stack using malloc:

```
char *buf = malloc(A_BIG_NUM);
```

Answer (score 2):

Stack size on *nix is usually set at 8MB by default. A char array of 11111111 elements is ~11MB, which is *much* larger than the stack. As a result it'll cause a stack overflow

You can increase stack size with `ulimit`, but increasing it too much is also not good. For big arrays you should use heap allocation instead

Answer (score 1):

Be reasonable. The array buf is used to read a number in textual form. Nobody needs to enter 1 billion digit numbers (except those trying buffer overflow attacks), no known C implementation supports exponents or mantissas for 1 billion digit float or double numbers.

The excessive and unnecessary array sizes exceed the implementation limit for stack sizes and result in a segmentation violation in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Everything has been written above. Program gets signal SIGSEGV when starting because of overcoming of allowed stack size.
Below is just one another way to determine the actual stack size (both soft and hard limits):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
void main() {
  struct rlimit rl;
  int ss = getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl);
  printf("soft = %lu, hard = %lu\n", rl.rlim_cur, rl.rlim_max);
}
```